# Fix Responsiveness in Small Screens With Less Code in Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-4, responsive

I'm currently using bootstrap 4 and i have this code below and it is working. However, i need to write it again in order to work on smaller screens which is bad.
So how can i fix this without to write code just for smaller screens like mobile devices?

```
      <!-- Medium to Large Screens -->
      <div class="row d-block d-md-none">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
          <ul class="profile-menu no-list-style">
            <li routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/a']">A</a>
            </li>
            <li routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/b']">B</a>
            </li>
            <li routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/c]">C</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
          <ul class="profile-menu no-list-style">
            <li routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/d']">D</a>
            </li>
            <li routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/e']">E</a>
            </li>
            <li routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/f']">F</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Medium to Large Screens -->

      <!-- Small Screens -->
      <div class="row d-none d-md-block">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
          <ul class="profile-menu no-list-style">
            <li routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/a']">A</a>
            </li>
            <li routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/b']">B</a>
            </li>
            <li routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/c]">C</a>
            </li>
           <li routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/d']">D</a>
            </li>
            <li routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/e']">E</a>
            </li>
            <li routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/f']">F</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Small Screens -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below. On mobile, it should auto create the `col-sm-12` and `col-12` by default on smaller screens unless you have some override.

If this doesn't work, show us the screenshot on mobile device.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
      <ul class="profile-menu no-list-style">
        <li routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/a']">A</a>
        </li>
        <li routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/b']">B</a>
        </li>
        <li routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/c]">C</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
      <ul class="profile-menu no-list-style">
        <li routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/d']">D</a>
        </li>
        <li routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/e']">E</a>
        </li>
        <li routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/f']">F</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I have tried that but the problem is there's a space on C and D

Comment: `@media(max-width:767px) { ul { margin-bottom: 0;}}` would solve it. I suggest creating a new class though.